# Proof that infinite functions can fit a table of numerical values

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, interpolation

Suppose while conducting experiments, I measure a finite number of variables with some constants like temperature, etc. We get a table of finite number measurements (numerical values to some decimal digits of accuracy). Like the table shown here:

[image]

where constant1, constant2, etc. are boundary conditions.

My question is whether we can always find infinitely many $C^{\infty}$ functions that fit data of this type in an equation that can give measured values from the boundary conditions of the experiment?

If yes, how can we prove it?

Note:

If information provided is ambiguous or insufficient, please comment below so that I can provide. Thank you!

Comment: If your question is: can we find an arbitrary amount of functions that fit values in a certain table, the answer would be yes. No need to frame it as a pseudo-question about science. That's certainly not what science is about.

Comment: Yes, I changed it now

Comment: @user5198: Are there any conditions on what functions we can use? A finite number of points can already be interpolated by infinitely many polynomials, or by infinitely many piecewise constant functions, or ...

Comment: I added the constraint on functions. No piecewise functions are allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove there are an infinite number of polynomials that fit, you can just find the [interpolating polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolating_polynomial).  Then you can add $a\prod(x-x_i)$ where the $x_i$ are your measurement points for any value of $a$ to it.

Comment: yes! because you are adding zero to the interpolating polynomial for all values of x_i. Thanks